# Issue With ClaimsIdentity In .NET Core 2 Middleware Solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, claims-based-identity

Just started on my first .net core 2 web app implementation. Unfortunately due to business requirements,the user has to authenticated via an legacy forms login, username/password is handled to an oracle db and when user is authenticated, a session id is generated and appended to the base url of the app that is launched. Very old school but it works.

As you can imagine the session id expires so it must be validated by my app. Easy enough, I pass the session id that I retrieve from the querystring to my Oracle API and the response is a object that contains user information such as firstname, lastname, etc.

After this API call completes successfully, I then create a new ClaimsIdentity and Principal and call the SignInAsync() method.

I currently do this in custom middleware I have registered in my Startup.cs. I would handle this the usual way in a Login Controller method, but since there is no login in my app, I cannot see any other way but in the middleware I wrote.

```
public class AuthenticationHandler
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private HttpService _httpService;

    public AuthenticationHandler(RequestDelegate next, HttpService httpService)
    {
        _httpService = httpService;
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, [FromServices] HttpService httpService)
    {
        if (context.Request.Query.Count == 1)
        {
            var sessionId = context.Request.Query.FirstOrDefault().Value;
            var session = await _httpService.ValidateSession(sessionId);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(session?.UserId))
            {
                var claims = new List<Claim>()
                {
                    new Claim(CustomClaimTypes.UserId, session.UserId),
                    new Claim(CustomClaimTypes.BuId, session.BuId),
                    new Claim(CustomClaimTypes.SecurityLevel, session.SecurityLevel)
                };

                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "TNReadyEVP");
                var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

                await Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.SignInAsync(context, principal);

                var isIn = principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
                var isAuthed = (context.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).IsAuthenticated;
                await _next.Invoke(context);
            }
            else
            {
                Terminate(context);
            }
        }

        return;
    }

    private async void Terminate(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Invalid User");
        return;
    }
}

public static class MiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder ValidateSession(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<AuthenticationHandler>();
    }
}
```

So far so good, I believe this is the correct solution. However when I attempt to get claims via a small API I have in my app as seen below, the claims are empty and the User.Identity.Authenticated is false.

What am I missing here? Thanks for the advice, this is one of those weird edge cases that I haven't had to deal with before...therefore the need for custom middleware.

```
    [HttpGet("claims")]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Claim>> Get()
    {
        var claims = (User as ClaimsPrincipal).Claims;
        return await Task.FromResult(claims);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You really shouldn’t use your own middleware for this. The built-in authentication and authorization stack is more than powerful enough to handle your situation. In fact, Barry Dorrans, the .NET security PM responsible for the auth stack of the ASP.NET Core project [basically† said in a talk](https://youtu.be/fBUumVyafHw) that if it doesn’t work for your use case, you should drop him an email and they would fix it.

Instead, you should consider writing your own authentication handler for this purpose. That way, you get the whole authentication and authorization infrastructure without additional hurdles. Everything will just work.

To do this, you basically have to implement and register an [`IAuthenticationHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationhandler-1).

I’d suggest you to look at the [`CookieAuthenticationHandler`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs) since it does a kind-of similar job as what you are trying to do: Reconstructing a claims identity from information that was sent with the HTTP request. Just that you are using a query argument and a database instead of the cookie data.

Depending on how you want to have the general application flow work, you might even consider turning this into a remote authentication provider, combining it with the cookie authentication—like a dumbed down OAuth process: You get a request and if you do not have a cookie, you challenge your custom authentication handler which redirects to your legacy login mask. There, you log in and it sends you back to a special URL of your application with the session id attached (e.g. `/signin-session?sessionid=12345`). Your remote authentication handler handles that request, queries the database and constructs an identity from the information and passes that on to the cookie authentication handler. That one will then persist the identity in a secure cookie, so you no longer need to query the database on every request, and you also no longer need the session id in every single URL.

<sub>† To be fair, he was only talking about the authorization part there; but I’m sure he also meant it for the whole stack since it’s really powerful.</sub>

Comment: Thx for the details. You make a very valid point, as I was experimenting last night, I came to the conclusion I was trying to force the middleware to work for a case that its not designed for. 

Reviewing the docs for CookieAuthenticationHandler and looking at this as well: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?tabs=aspnetcore2x

I basically have the bulk of code ready, just need to refactor. There's a few other edge cases...such as only firing the auth provider when a specific url path is hit, but aside from that, I think I got a good start...thanks!